# How should i interact with a base of words in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, data-structures

I'm making a word game for iPhone. User can construct words from separate letters. And i need to check is this a real word, which user made, or some kind of pointless stuff like "sfugh". How i should better implement this? Should i have kind dictionary in program(I think it's a bad idea, because with a large amount of words it would work very slow) or maybe there is kind of online dictionaries, where i can check the word from my code, or should i make a trie? Or maybe where is other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use a pre-populated sqlite database. That way, you can use string indexes to make the searches in the db faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's native [UITextChecker](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/index.html) to determine whether or not a word is misspelled/valid. [Here's a sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/morganchen12/TextCheckerTest/blob/master/TextCheckerTest/ViewController.m#L45). This way, you don't have to worry about assembling your own database full of words.

For easy digestion, here's the code that does all the work

```
- (IBAction)textFieldTextDidChange:(id)sender {
    NSRange rangeOfMisspelling = [self.textChecker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:self.textField.text
                                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, self.textField.text.length)
                                                                      startingAt:0
                                                                            wrap:NO
                                                                        language:@"en_US"];
    // no misspellings
    if (rangeOfMisspelling.location == NSNotFound) {
        self.textLabel.text = @"Valid word!";
    }

    // misspellings
    else {
        self.textLabel.text = @"Not a word.";
    }
}
```

One thing to note is UITextChecker seems to count individual letters as valid words.